# Single line statements

Tags: c, ansi-c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    int i,max,max2;     

    int arr[10];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)   arr[i]=rand()%101;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)   printf("%d\n",arr[i]);

    max=arr[0]; 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(max < arr[i])    max2=max;   max=arr[i];

    }
    printf("Max is : %d\n",max);
    printf("2nd max is : %d",max2);
}
```

Output :
32
32
54
12
52
56
8
30
44
94

Max is : 94

2nd max is : 44

But when I change my 'if' statement to

```
if(max < arr[i])
    {   
        max2=max;
        max=arr[i];
    }
```

It works fine !

Max is : 94

2nd max is : 56

I've previously used more than one operation in a single line statement like

```
if(xyz) doSomething; break;
```

But it doesn't work here, why?

Comment: In C code new-lines are just sugar.

Comment: Well, except for pre-processor macros :-)

Comment: Don't get into the habit of doing this. It is bad style. Always put the curly brackets.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well yes, although one *could* argue the preprocessor isn't part of the C language itself. But only part of ... well .. the preprocessor. ;-)

Comment: yeah thanks for the advice, but I just feel a bit lazy sometimes so I do this sin  : )

Comment: C code can be written to be very difficult to read/understand (there are contests for that kind of code)   In general, C code needs to be written so it can be easily read/understood.  That is why there are axioms like: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  I.E. readability by a human is the most important criteria (after the criteria of the code performing the desired operation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "*single line statement*" in C, as C does not care about new-lines. They are used only to help the reader read.

This

```
if(max < arr[i])    max2=max;   max=arr[i];
```

is equivalent to

```
if(max < arr[i])    
  max2=max;   
max=arr[i];
```

is equivalent to

```
if(max < arr[i])    
{
  max2=max;   
}
max=arr[i];
```

Comment: exactly: `char O,o[];main(l){for(;~l;O||puts(o))O=(O[o]=~(l=getchar())?4<(4^l>>5)?l:46:0)?-~O&printf("%02x ",l)*5:!O;}` (code is not mine)